# switch to another branch without committing

Tags: git

I am working on a feature branch and have not finished the work there - Now I need to change to a different branch to fix something

for example

```
feat1 - 6+ files changed
```

When I checkout to feat2 branch, after `git add .` in feat1, git seems to carry over the staged yet uncommitted file changes.

If I commit these file changes in feat1, checking out to feat2 will not carry over those changes

How can I switch branches without committing file changes?

Comment: Use this command `GIT stash `

Comment: @ZachRussell: It's `git stash`, not `GIT stash`.

Comment: Yes my stupid phone is autocorrecting :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) them:

```
$ git stash save -u "Some logical description of the changes"
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: Some logical description of the changes
$ git checkout other-branch
```

When you're done, you can use `git stash apply` to apply the changes in your stash and keep the stash around, or `git stash pop` to apply the changes and remove the stash as long as there are no conflicts.

If you end up with multiple stashes at once you can `apply` or `pop` them in an arbitrary order using the `stash@` string, e.g. `git stash apply stash@{6}`.

Comment: but doesn't stash work like a stack? I must stash pop to revert back. Won't this be a problem if I work on multiple feature branches?

Comment: @NickGinanto, you can `apply` or `pop` arbitrary stashes. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, stash defaults to stack-like behavior, but you can specify a *specific* item on the stash: `git stash list` prints them as `stash@{1}` etc, and you can apply and drop a specific one.

Comment: is that the "best-practice" approach to work on several branches at once? or is the git way is to work and finish working on a certain branch?

Comment: @NickGinanto, we're getting into opinion here. `git stash` is a tool; use it when you feel it's appropriate. You can also use `git commit` and optionally rewrite your history later, or create a temporary branch, or...

Answer (score 5):

Most people recommend `git stash`.

I prefer just doing a `git commit`.  You can always `git commit --amend` later.  Just make sure not to push that particular commit.  If it helps—and for me, it does—just make a branch for "work in progress on feature".  For instance:

```
$ git checkout zorg
Branch zorg set up to track remote branch zorg from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'zorg'
... work ...
```

At this point, I realize I need to save the work-so-far and go do something else:

```
$ git checkout -b zorg-stones-1
Switched to a new branch 'zorg-stones-1'
$ git commit
```

Now everything is all nicely saved away on a local branch that I have named in a way that helps me remember what I was doing, when I come back later.

Often, I come back later to find that `origin/zorg` has been updated, so:

```
$ git fetch
[shows that origin/zorg is updated]
$ git checkout zorg && git merge --ff-only origin/zorg
[now local branch zorg is updated too; --ff-only is just for paranoia]
$ git checkout zorg-stones-1
$ git rebase zorg
[rebase messages here]
```

If the rebase does not go well (or I need to rework things), I use `git rebase --abort` (or just skip the rebase attempt) and then start a new `zorg-stones-2` branch based on the updated `zorg`.  When I'm good about it, I commit often enough and don't have to do a lot of `git rebase -i zorg` to fix it up a whole lot before doing `git checkout zorg; git merge zorg-stones-N` to bring in the final version, ready to `git push` or whatever.

I often have a bunch of `blah-mods-N` branches to (eventually) delete this way.  It's definitely true that `stash`ing is less branch-clutter-y.  But I prefer to have everything I did accessible by name up until I deliberately toss it out.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `git stash`

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing explains your exact case-scenario

Answer (score 1):

Even if you did not finish your work I would suggest committing them.

Committing is always a good idea. - However, pushing is usually only a good idea when you are finished.

If your commits are not perfect you can always clean them up or combine them using something like `git rebase -i` before pushing them.